# I want to play DVD slide shows in Ubuntu. What program is the best?

Tags: software-recommendation, video, slideshow

I have several slide shows on DVDs and would like to play them on Ubuntu. What programs will support this action?

Answer (score 0):

If it is a slide show you should use **Libre Office Impress**.

If it is just a video resembling slide show use **Totem video player**.